# How to use Curve modifier with existing several edges as curve object?

Tags: modeling

How to use Curve modifier with existing several edges as curve object?

Sorry guys I edited and added screenshots.
This is the upper part of target cloth.

[image: The cloth object]

I selected existing edges and added some by knife and created one object then convert it to curve object by pressing Alt + C. 
Now the object acts like a curve.

[image: The line is now curve and acts like curve.]

The purpose of the line(curve) is applying curve modifier to the cloth to make wrinkles. However, when I tried to apply curve modifier to the blue cloth, there is no selectable curve object on the property of curve modifier. I selected manually then error message appeared and can't proceed.

[image: The converted curve object won't appear and can't select.]

Is there any ways to use Curve Modifier with converted curve object?
Or, if bezier Curve is necessary to Curve modifier, then how to (re)shape bezier curve object as same as the existing line(several number of edges)?

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Can you post a picture to help us understand what you are asking?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: What object did you add Curve modifier to? Curve modifier should be added to mesh object you want to be curved and in its settings curve object as target should be choosed.

Comment: The blue cloth is the one to apply curve modifier and hoped the curved object (converted from several edges) will be appear as a candidate for 'Object:' but won't. I manually selected but error msg appeared...

Comment: What kind of curve is it? Can you make a small [sample file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) replicating the situation?

Comment: Sure. This is the sample .blend file.  http://www.mediafire.com/file/zub28qv15lu5byu/curve-issue-sample.blend